# OSX Terminal not recognizing ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile on startup

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

The only way my .bashrc and .bashprofile are recognized by OSX is if I specify in my terminal's preferences for the file to be targeted upon boot. Is there a reason why they're not working like they should be?

Here's the inside of my .bashrc

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # 
Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
#Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH 
variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
smiley () { echo -e ":\\$(($??50:51))"; }
export PS1="\h\$(smiley) \e[30;1m\w\e[0m\n\$ "
```

Inside of .bash_profile

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # 
Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH n . 
variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
alias b='cd ..'
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why would it matter whats in them?

Comment: @123 i figured that i had to have some sort of config which links the bashrc and bashprofile to my terminal shell. i'm not too familiar with bash so i wasn't sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In OSX, all sessions are login sessions and will not source `$HOME/.bashrc`, they will source `$HOME/.profile` or `$HOME/.bash_profile`. So put the following in your `.bash_profile`

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then                                                            
 source ~/.bashrc                                                                
fi
```

Comment: that did the trick! just curious but why doesn't it show the source ~/.bashrc upon load? is this different from a terminal startup command?